# Please verify my proof for the lemma: "If $X_n \to_d X$ and $X_n + Y_n \to_d X$ with $X_n$ and $Y_n$ independent for each $n$, then $Y_n \to_p 0$"

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions, probability-limit-theorems

It is the lemma 5.1 in this paper: https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/1193/docs/lin.pdf, and the paper contains the proof.

My attempt is:

By Portmanteau theorem, $X_n \to_d X$ is the equivalent as $\phi_{X_n}(t) \to_d \phi_X (t)$ for any $t \in \mathbb R$, so $X_n \to_d X$ implies that $\phi_{X_n}(t) \to \phi_X (t)$, and $X_n + Y_n \to_d X$ implies that $\phi_{X_n + Y_n}(t) = \phi_{X_n} (t) \phi_{Y_n} (t) \to \phi_X(t)$ for any $t \in \mathbb R$-- the equality holds by the independence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$. Therefore, it must be that $\phi_{Y_n} (t) \to 1 = E[e^{i t\cdot 0}]$ for any $t \in \mathbb R$, which implies that $Y_n \to_d 0$. Since the convergence in distribution to a constant value is equivalent as the convergence in probability to a constant value, it follows that $Y_n \to_p 0$.

I cannot see what in my proof might be wrong, but my proof concerns me, because it seems to be too simple compared to the one in the paper.

Comment: Not sure if that's a big issue or not, but don't you need $\phi_{X_n}(t)$ and $\phi_X(t)$ not to vanish "too much" to get your conclusion $\phi_{Y_n}(t)\to 1$?

Comment: @md5 You're right. I don't think $\phi_{Y_n}(t) \to 1$ for all $t$ follows. However, I vaguely recall that in Levy's theorem it suffices to have $\phi_n \to \phi$ in some neighbourhood of $0$. Since $\phi_{X_n}(0) = \phi_X(0) = 1$, and they are continuous, this should remove the vanish too much issue.

Comment: On the last paragraph of page 10 of the linked paper, Goldstein mentions that they took pains to avoid using characteristic functions. Maybe that's the reason for the proof as it appears there? Anyway, there's the catch in using the right version of Levy's theorem, but besides that the above looks okay to me. I might be missing something subtle though...